# Using the collection's DisplayName from within DisplayTemplate for a single element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

To begin with, the code we have no problems with. It's a model:

```
    [DisplayName("A very hot hotshot")]
    public Person Hotshot { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Just a developer")]
    public Person Developer { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Some random guy")]
    public Person RandomGuy { get; set; }
```

And then we have a view which looks like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Hotshot)
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Developer)
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.RandomGuy)
```

DisplayTemplate for `Person` has a line which uses model's `DisplayName`:

```
@Html.DisplayNameForModel()
```

It's all nice, but the problem appears when you add a list property to the model and try to display it with `DisplayFor`. Here's the model part:

```
[DisplayName("Funny guys")]
public IEnumerable<Person> FunnyGuys { get; set; }
```

And, as `DisplayFor` is capable of displaying `IEnumerable<T>` iterating the `T` template, I'm calling it just like for other properties:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.FunnyGuys)
```

It works great, except for fetching that `DisplayName` from the containing collection. It's set to null, since the attribute is on `IEnumerable` property, and the template gets a single element from it.

I had to use the workaround:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.FunnyGuys, new {CollectionDisplayName = "Funny guys"})
```

And then using that property if `DisplayName` is null in `Person` template.

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `DisplayNameFor` helper is what are you looking for:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FunnyGuys)
```

Also it's better to use `Display` attribute over `DisplayName` becose it's come from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace and you can use not only literals in it but also **resorses** in your project. In case is you will localize your application.

```
[Display(Name = "Funny guys")]
```

Comment: I guess that would work if I wanted to display the name in "main" view (that one where I'm calling all the `DisplayFor`'s). But I'm looking for a way to display it from the `Person.cshtml` DisplayTemplate. The template itself knows nothing about the property. `DisplayFor` just puts each of `FunnyGuys` items in it, one at a time.